# Python: doubling variable in a function

Tags: python, function

```
    def lb(a):
    while a != 0:
        a = a - 1
        print('\n')
```

```
print('1 line break')
lb(1)
print('2 line breaks')
lb(2)
print('3 line breaks')
lb(3)
print('done')
```

When I run this code it doubles the amount of lines it needs to break, 
so it outputs:

```
    1 line break
```

```
2 line breaks



3 line breaks
```

How do I make it print the right amount of line breaks?

Comment: Just a note, perhaps you could change your lb function to be just `print('\n') * a`

Comment: btw it works fine. May be you add more statements with more line breaks as 8-10 so you can identify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python `print` automatically adds a line break at the end unless explicitly told not to. This means that your function will print twice the number of line breaks asked because

```
print('\n')
```

prints TWO line breaks, one that is in the string and another that is added automatically at the end.

A simple solution is to use `print()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

print will add a '\n' automatically

```
def lb(a):
    print '\n'*(a-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def lb(x):
    for i in range(x):
        print ''
```

Quick and dirty. Not so pythonic, but it works well enough for me. Still could compare using range vs xrange, but this gets the job done.